# Uploading a `XML` file not working as per expected

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I required to upload a `xml` file in to server using the `angular` `resource`. i am trying but getting an error as `Uncaught TypeError: server.uploadXML.post is not a function`

any one correct me or show me the correct way to handle this?
to do this process, I am using `controller` and `directive` with my `html`.

I am very new, please guide me wherever I made mistaken.

here is my controller function : //i am calling from directive

```
$scope.uploadFile = function ( newFile, id ) {

                 var fileData = new FormData();
                 fileData.append('file', newFile[0], newFile[0].name);
                // console.log("new file", "$scope.packageId", $scope.packageId, "$scope.contractorId", $scope.contractorId, newFile, info );

                server.uploadXML.post({

                    packageId: $scope.packageId, 
                    contractorId : $scope.contractorId,
                    contractId : id

                }, { save: {
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: fileData,
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    processData: false, 
                    contentType: "application/octet-stream", 
                    success : function ( data ) {

                    },
                    error : function ( error ) {

                        cosole.log( error );

                    }

                }} ); 

            }
```

Here is my directive:

```
//file upload handled here

var uploadFileDirective = function () {

    return {

        restrict : 'C',

        scope : {

            info:"=",
            upload:"="

        },

        link:function ( scope, element, attrs ) {

            element.on('change', function ( event ) {

                var files = event.target.files;
                scope.upload(files, scope.info ); //calling controller

            })
        }

    }

}

angular.module("tcpApp")
.directive("uploadFileDirective", uploadFileDirective);
```

Here is my HTML :

```
<div class="row row3">
                            <div class="cell">
                                <a ng-href="">Contract Details</a>
                                <span class="fileUpload">
                                    Upload Report 
                                    <!-- hanlded by directive by class name  -->
                                    <input info="contractor.Id" upload="uploadFile" class="uploadField upload-file-directive" type="file" />
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
```

I am using my `server.js` file to upload my file, here is the server.js file:

```
(function () {

    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("tcpApp")
        .factory("server", ['$resource', function ($resource) {

            var base = 'http://azvsptcsdev02:678/_vti_bin/CPMD.WEBSERVICE/ProjectInfoService.svc/';

            return {

                subPage : $resource( base + 'GetSubProjects/:id'),

                splash : $resource( base + 'GetProjectDetails'),

                projectSummary : $resource( base  + 'GetProjectByID/:id', {id : '@id'}), //at the top on the summary page

                contractorsList : $resource( base + 'Contracts/:projectId/:subProjectId/:phaseId/:disciplineId'), //left side list of contractos

                contractorInfo : $resource( base + 'Projects/:projectId/:subProjectId/:contractId/:disciplineId/:staticId'), //summary page getting contractor info

                allProjectList : $resource( base + 'GetAllProjects'), //getting all project for all project page

                allSubProjects : $resource( base + 'GetAllSubProjects/:packageId'),

                allContracts : $resource( base + 'AllContracts/:packageId/:contractorId'),

                uploadXML   : $resource( base + 'UploadContract/:packageId/:contractorId/:contractId')


            }

        }]);

})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `server.js` file, when you do

```
uploadXML   : $resource( base + 'UploadContract/:packageId/:contractorId/:contractId')
```

`$resource` returns on abject with the following methods available:

```
{ 'get':    {method:'GET'},
  'save':   {method:'POST'},
  'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true},
  'remove': {method:'DELETE'},
  'delete': {method:'DELETE'} };
```

See the angular [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource).

So `server.uploadXML.post` is indeed not defined (that's why you get the error). Try using `server.uploadXML.save` instead which corresponds to the http POST method.

Comment: I agree, But why i am not getting any message from "succces" or "error"? in my save parameter?

Comment: And i am getting this in console not in save prams. `Invalid HTTP status code 405` - what is this mean?

Comment: status code 405 means the HTTP method you used (i.e. POST) is not allowed. So either your server does not support it, or your client and server have different domains in which case your client needs to be allowed to make cross origin requests (CORS) see this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS